# Android - Could not find method onButtonClick(View)

Tags: android, android-layout, button, buttonclick

I have a problem with the button id "btn_scansiona" once I click on it the following traceback is trigged:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method onButtonClick(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'btn_scansiona'
                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod(AppCompatViewInflater.java:325)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:284)
                                                                           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
                                                                           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

fragment_scan.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.test.myapp.ScanFragment">


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="keywords"
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:textSize="20dp" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="scansiona"
    android:id="@+id/btn_scansiona"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
    android:background="#ffaa00"
    android:onClick="onButtonClick" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Insert keywords"
    android:id="@+id/textSearch"
    android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:textColor="@color/abc_input_method_navigation_guard"
    android:textIsSelectable="false"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:selectAllOnFocus="false" />
```

ScanFragment.java

```
public class ScanFragment extends Fragment {
// TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

// TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;

private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

public ScanFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

/**
 * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
 * this fragment using the provided parameters.
 *
 * @param param1 Parameter 1.
 * @param param2 Parameter 2.
 * @return A new instance of fragment ScanFragment.
 */
// TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
public static ScanFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    ScanFragment fragment = new ScanFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }

}



@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_scan, container, false);
}

// TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    try {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(context.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}

//DB
private DbManager db=null;
private CursorAdapter adapter;
String date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(new Date());

public void onButtonClick(View view){
    //do something when button is clicked.
    EditText txt=(EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.textSearch);
    if (txt.length()>0 && date.length()>0)
    {
        db.save(txt.getEditableText().toString(), date);
        adapter.changeCursor(db.query());
    }
}
```

}

If I declare the method "onButtonClick" on MainActivity.java the following traceback disappear but I receive another traceback regarding the "txt.length" cannot be null.
Where is my mistake? thanks
Daniele

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the `onClick` method should be present in the parent activity, so that's why the error ain't coming in case you move the code to the activity class

**OR**

If you want to have it in your fragment then you'll have to initialize the button in fragment and set the `onClickListener` for it, something like this :

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

   View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout. fragment_scan,
    container, false);
   Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_scansiona);
   button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
   {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View v)
             {
                // do something
             } 
   }); 
   return view;
}
```

and you're getting `txt.length()` can't be null error because :

- You've defined `txt` as your `EditText` and it's not the text inside it. You'll have to fetch the `text` and convert it to `String` like this :

  - `txt.getText().toString()`

then you can do your normal processing like this :

```
txt.getText().toString().length()
```

Comment: This did the job! Thank you very much for the explanation

Answer (score 0):

Move your method  'onButtonClick' to your activity.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of defining the `ButtonClickListener` method in the layout. why dont you define the `buttonClickListener` in the code.

Remove `android:onClick` tag from layout and in code and use

```
Button btnScan = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_scansiona
btnScan.onClickListener(.....) {
    //your rest code here....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must define that method in the activity.

BTW I suggest using [Butterknife](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife') library if you want to write your code this way.  It's very easy:

```
public class FancyFragment extends Fragment {

     @Override public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fancy_fragment, container, false); 
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
        return view; 
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.submit) public void submit(View view) {
         // do something ... }
     }

   }
```

build.gradle

```
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.1.0'
apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compile
```