# Android Cannot find views

Tags: java, android, fragment

For example, I have **A, B, C and main** activity xml with **A, B, C main** java respectively.

I was trying to put a frame layout in **main**
I have also create **FM_A, FM_B and FM_C** which is a fragment java **linked to A, B, C layout xml**

Since **main** is a navigation bar activity, I replace the **frame layout** in main with fragment, it was all successful.

Until I tried to use the button in the layout, an error saying:

```
Could not find method saveSetting(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'btnSave'
```

With the activity alone without accesssing them with fragment, it can be normally functioned, is that my way of doing so is a mistake?

Ref link:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ju837bQOBfg&spfreload=5

UPDATE: code added

**Setting.java**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_setting);

    startLinking();
    startSharedPreferences();

    // Check for second entry
    if (sharedPreferences.getString("Name", "") != null)
    {
        displayInfo();
        btnEdit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        btnSave.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        btnClear.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        btnGoWelcome.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        etxtName.setEnabled(false);
        etxtFood.setEnabled(false);
        spinnerBreed.setEnabled(false);
    }
}
public void startLinking()
{
    etxtName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etxtName);
    etxtFood = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etxtFood);
    btnSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
    btnClear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnClear);
    btnEdit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnEdit);
    btnGoWelcome = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGoWelcome);

    spinnerBreed = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerBreed);
    adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.breedNameArr, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinnerBreed.setAdapter(adapter);
}

public void startSharedPreferences()
{
    sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
}

public void saveSetting(View view)
{
    String petName, breed, food, userID;
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(etxtName.getText().toString()) == true || spinnerBreed.getCount() == 0 || TextUtils.isEmpty(etxtFood.getText().toString()) == true)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please fill all the info!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    } else
    {
        editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString("Name", etxtName.getText().toString());
        editor.putString("Food", etxtFood.getText().toString());
        editor.putInt("BreedPos", spinnerBreed.getSelectedItemPosition());
        editor.putString("Breed", spinnerBreed.getSelectedItem().toString());
        editor.commit();

        Toast.makeText(this, "SAVE SUCCESS!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        btnEdit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        btnSave.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        btnClear.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        btnGoWelcome.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        etxtName.setEnabled(false);
        etxtFood.setEnabled(false);
        spinnerBreed.setEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

**FM_Setting.java (fragment)**

```
public class FM_Setting extends Fragment
{
View myview;
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    myview=inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_setting, container, false);
    return myview;
}
}
```

**activity_setting.xml**

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/save"
    android:id="@+id/btnSave"
    android:onClick="saveSetting"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:textColor="@color/colorTitleBar"
    android:layout_below="@+id/etxtFood"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
```

Comment: Please add your code ..this info is not sufficient to answer your question.

Comment: Can you share the code where you set the `OnClickListener` on the `Button`?

Comment: Thank you guys for your reply. I set it in the XML file with onClick method , I am posting the code now

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - Could not find method onButtonClick(View)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38174136/android-could-not-find-method-onbuttonclickview)

Comment: @petey thanks for your help, I can get rid of the error now.

Comment: @petey However, those method seems to be doing nothing for me now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a corresponding method in your `main` Activity to the `onClick` defined in your XML. Hard to tell with no code sample, but I suspect it's undefined or you moved it to the fragment class. The `onClick` in XML must correspond to a method in an Activity.

```
public void saveSetting(View v){

}
```

Alternatively, you could find the view within your fragment and set the `OnClickListener` programmatically, then remove the `onClick` line from the XML. This is common practice.

```
View view = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                saveSetting(v);
            }
        });
```

Comment: thank you for your comments, I didn't realize the onClick in xml cannot apply to fragment, thanks for the reminding bro

Comment: It returns a null reference error on view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 

Which is :
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference

Comment: Your question didn't have the XML when I wrote the answer - I suspect you might have pasted in my code without changing the ID (I just wrote an example ID since I didn't know your ID). It needs to the the ID of the view you want in findViewByID(//ID); I've updated the answer with the btnSave ID now I can see your XML.

Comment: thank you, I want to ask if I should declare the saveSetting method inside the fragment? And remove the entire method from the setting activity? So it means when you have a fragment, it is not only simply referring to the method in activity but instead you should implement all the method you need in fragment?

Comment: You're welcome. Yes you can move it to your fragment in this case, just remember when you need to access the context (for example, where you have "this" in the Toast.makeText, you'll need *getActivity()* instead of *this*

Comment: I know more about fragment now thanks a lot, btw I still got error :
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference

Do I need to add something before the fragment launched?

Comment: Is the xml above the entire xml for that layout? You'd need to have the button in a layout like LinearLayout or RelativeLayout. I suggest looking up tutorials on layouts and fragments.

Comment: I can finally using everything as suggested.
Replace "this" with getActivity() and replace "findviewbyid" with "view.findviewbyid"

Comment: Glad you got sorted :)